# Visual Studio IDE language layout

Tags: visual-studio

When you run VS2005+ for the first time after installing it, you are given the option to specify a layout that is tailored for your primary programming language.

**Question:** How can I later change my preferred layout to another language? (For example, from Visual Basic to C#.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools, Import & Export Settings, Reset All Settings.